# meteor react fullcalendar implementation

Tags: meteor, reactjs, fullcalendar, meteor-react

I'm very new to meteor and I am completely stuck on how to do the following: 
I'd like to use react as the view layer. Therefore I'm using themeteorchef base as boiler plate. I would like to add fullcalendar for displaying data a calendar. There are a couple of packages which provide fullcalendar in meteor. See https://atmospherejs.com/?q=fullcalendar . However when using these, they all seem to rely on blaze as templating engine... I tried converting the blaze template to a react component by using this package:  https://atmospherejs.com/thereactivestack/blazetoreact 
However I'm a bit in the dark on how to do this, anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using React now, I would just look for React components that do the same thing. I discovered a Full Calendar React component for you:

[Demo Page](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html)

[GitHub](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar)

[Npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-calendar)

It seems to be pretty popular on npm, hope it works for you.